# Unable to update the version of windows phone app on Store

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have published the windows phone app. Now I have added new feature and functionality in my app.On windows phone developer console we have two options Replace the Package or Add new package.
I had selected Replace option and now the submission has been submitted successfully.
But windows app store not showing the update notification for my app but if I uninstall and again install the app new version of app installed.
I want windows store should give update notification for new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default your phone only checks for updates every 24 hours.
You can manually check for updates using the store app's settings.

Comment: Thank you dude, I was thinking I made some mistake during deployment.